# How to add onload event for gapi?

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client

I am using Google API (gapi) for user log in.

My code is below. It loads google sdk asynchronously. Once it is loaded I need to call the api function `gapi.auth.authorize`

```
(function(d: any, s: string, id: string) {
    var js: HTMLScriptElement, gjs: Element = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js";
    gjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, gjs);

    if (js.readyState){  //IE
        js.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (js.readyState == "loaded" ||
                js.readyState == "complete"){
                js.onreadystatechange = null;
                gapi.auth.authorize();   //<-- details omitted 
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        js.onload = function(){
            gapi.auth.authorize();   //<-- details omitted 
        };
    }
}(document, 'script', 'google-jssdk'));
```

Now the issue is - I get error

> TypeError: gapi.auth is undefined

It should be defined right? I looked at the console, and typed `gapi.auth` and I get an object in response.

So I believe that `js.onload` event is getting triggered early, i.e when `gapi.auth` is not ready.

How to fix this? Or more specifically how to add onload event for gapi?

Comment: I have the same problem.  I am using chrome on mac os.  I am loading synchronously and when I type `gapi.auth` into the console it is still `undefined` and when I type `gapi` I get an object with many properties such as `client`, `plus`, etc. but no `auth`.  Does this have something to do with the APIs enabled from the developer console?  All I enabled was the Google+ API.

Answer (score 3):

What browser is this seen in? Also, you need to include a `?onload=myFunction` parameter at the end of the script's `src` attribute, then implement `window['myFunction'] = function() { ... }` to detect library readiness. The loading typically injects an additional script node and you'll need to wait for that one, too.

Comment: confused me at first, but then I realized you were talking about on the script tag, like this: `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=appStart" async defer></script>` then it totally worked after I implemented my callback function, appStart.

Answer (score 0):

window.gapi_onload = function() { gapi.auth.authorize(); }

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the package [gapi-script](https://github.com/partnerhero/gapi-script), this package provides the gapi instantly, so you don't have to wait any script to load, just import it and use:

```
import { gapi } from 'gapi-script';
```

And the package also has a function to initialize the gapi auth2:

```
import { loadAuth2 } from 'gapi-script';

let auth2 = await loadAuth2(clientId, scopes);
```